# Disqus count.js returns the wrong comment count and reaction count

Tags: disqus

I have a blog article hosted [here](http://in-the-attic.com/2013/01/04/building-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap-and-github-pages-a-beginners-guide/) that has comments hosted on Disqus. For some reason the called to count.js doesn't seem to be returning the correct number of comments. I've noticed this on a few blog entries on the same site, but oddly, not all of them... The page makes a request to http://intheatticuk.disqus.com/count-data.js?q=1&54=1,%2F2013%2F01%2F04%2Fbuilding-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap-and-github-pages-a-beginners-guide%2F as you would expect, but the response is:

```
{
    "showReactions":true,
    "text":{
        "and":"and",
        "reactions":{
            "zero":"0 Reactions",
            "multiple":"{num} Reactions",
            "one":"1 Reaction"
        },
        "comments":{
            "zero":"0 Comments",
            "multiple":"{num} Comments",
            "one":"1 Comment"
        }
    },
    "counts":[{
        "reactions":0,
        "uid":54,
        "comments":0
    }]
}
```

Which is obviously where the problem lies. If you go into the discussion and wait for Disqus to load you'll see it pulls through the comments just fine, there's 9 of them... Can anyone see something glaringly obvious that I'm missing? I've tried manually changing the ID that Disqus will use to find the comment threads the several different things such as:

1. %2Fbuilding-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap-and-github-pages-a-beginners-guide%2F (so removing the date)
2. %2Fbuilding-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap-and-github-pages-a-beginners-guide
3. building-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap-and-github-pages-a-beginners-guide%2F
4. building-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap-and-github-pages-a-beginners-guide

But none of these have worked and returned the correct count either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the absolute URL associated with that thread in your comment count href link instead of the relative url which you are currently using. The absolute URL should would be:

```
<a href="http://in-the-attic.com/2013/01/04/building-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap-and-github-pages-a-beginners-guide/">Comments</a>
```

If you are still not seeing the correct count display for that particular thread, you can [use an identifier](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-adding-comment-count-links-to-your-home-page#using-an-identifier):

```
<a href="http://in-the-attic.com/2013/01/04/building-a-blog-using-jekyll-bootstrap-and-github-pages-a-beginners-guide/" data-disqus-identifier="EXAMPLE">Comments</a>
```

Keep in mind that you cannot use the identifier until you have set one for that thread within the [Javascript configuration variables](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables#disqus_identifier)

Comment: Does not work. Also, why disqus have "data-disqus-url" then? I guess to avoid setting href value, so imo it is bad decision, because a lot of people may need to set href to one and disqus-url to another value.